# Part of NSString to NSNumber

Tags: objective-c

I need to input x and y co-ordinates into a custom object, the input is with the format "x,y"

I am currently storing the input as an `NSString` and need to get the integers out of it and into separate `NSNumbers`. If there is another way to store the input that would be easier, please explain.

I need to store x and y as separate `NSNumbers`, this also this needs to account for if x and y are 2 digits. i.e. `"23,4"`

can anyone help?

Comment: Separate the input string with componentsSeparatedByString with the separator being a comma so that you can have an array of subsets.

Comment: what if they are no 2 digits?

Comment: Why not use the CGPoint for storing coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-componentsSeparatedByString_)

```
NSArray *numericComponents = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSArray *numbers = [numericComponents map:^id(NSString *object) {
                       return @([object integerValue]);
                    }];
```

`map` here is simply a category method that I've added to `NSArray`:

```
@implementation NSArray (JRAdditions)

- (NSArray *)map:(id(^)(id))block {
    if([self count] == 0 || block == nil) return self;

    NSMutableArray *mapped = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSArray        *copy   = [self copy];

    for(id obj in copy) {
        id mappedObject = block(obj);

        if(mappedObject) {
            [mapped addObject:mappedObject];
        }
    }

    return [mapped copy];
}

@end
```

Comment: sorry im a bit of a noob, i dont understand how this works. could you explain

Comment: @user2113952 `@()` wraps a primitive value in a wrapper object such as an `NSNumber` or `NSValue`. I'm iterating through the collection returned from `-componentsSeparatedByString:` and creating a new collection that contains each numeric string as an `NSNumber` instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str=@"23,4";

NSArray *array=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSNumber *xNum=@([array[0] integerValue]);
NSNumber *yNum=@([array[1] integerValue]);
```

To check if they are two digits :

```
if ([xNum integerValue]>9 && [xNum integerValue]<100) {
    NSLog(@"x is 2 digits");
}
else{

}
if([yNum integerValue]>9 && [yNum integerValue]<100) {
    NSLog(@"y is 2 digits");
}
else{

}
```